# golang: declaring a camelcase in a struct declaration

Tags: go

I'm trying to read a yaml file via golang.

But the **"matchLabels"** sub-struct is not being recognized

**yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: nginx-deploy
    labels:
      app: test
spec:
    replicas: 3
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: web
```

**struct**

```
type myData struct {
    Apivesion string `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    Kind      string
    Metadata  struct {
        Name   string
        Labels struct {
            App string
        }
    }
    Spec struct {
        Replicas int64
        Selector struct {
            Matchlabels struct {
                App string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expectation**

```
&{apps/v1 Deployment {nginx-deploy {test}} {3 {{web}}}}
```

**Result**

```
&{apps/v1 Deployment {nginx-deploy {test}} {3 {{}}}}
```

**Fix didn't work:**

```
Matchlabels struct `yaml:"matchLabels"` {
```

Comment: Field tags follow the type: `Matchlabels struct { App string }  \`yaml:"matchLabels"\``

Comment: thank you thank you thank you.


So I treated the 'braces' as a value and added the `yaml...` qualifier after the struct.


But I should've treated the 'braces' as part of the struct-type and added the `yaml...` at the end.

Comment: `Matchlabels` -> `MatchLabels` - you need to capitalise the "L" to follow camelcase

Answer (score 1):

[Cerise Limón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%c3%b3n) gave the answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73494857/golang-declaring-a-camelcase-in-a-struct-declaration/73495106#comment129787130_73494857):

> Field tags follow the type:
>
> ```
> Matchlabels struct { App string } 
> `yaml:"matchLabels"`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you implemented the suggested answer correctly, see where the tag is:

```
type myData struct {
    Apivesion string `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    Kind      string
    Metadata  struct {
        Name   string
        Labels struct {
            App string
        }
    }
    Spec struct {
        Replicas int64
        Selector struct {
            Matchlabels struct {
                App string
            } `yaml:"matchLabels"`
        }
    }
}
```

See also: https://go.dev/play/p/yd9c-iBz2yL

Answer (score 0):

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    APIVersion string `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    Kind       string `yaml:"kind"`
    Metadata   struct {
        Name   string `yaml:"name"`
        Labels struct {
            App string `yaml:"app"`
        } `yaml:"labels"`
    } `yaml:"metadata"`
    Spec struct {
        Replicas int `yaml:"replicas"`
        Selector struct {
            MatchLabels struct {
                App string `yaml:"app"`
            } `yaml:"matchLabels"`
        } `yaml:"selector"`
    } `yaml:"spec"`
}
```

You can use this tool, it is really helpful:

> https://zhwt.github.io/yaml-to-go/